# Why do I need to extend my case class with a function signature to work in Sparks rdd.mapPartition?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, functional-programming

I am working on a Spark Streaming application (Direct API, version 2.3.2) that reads data from Kafka but I guess this is more a question on Scala itself.

Within the foreachRDD block I am transforming an RDD into another RDD. The transformation logic is defined in my case class

```scala
case class ExtractTableInfo(notUsed: Boolean = true)
{

  def apply(rdd: Iterator[(String, String)]): Iterator[(String, String))] =
    rdd.map { tuple  =>
      val (key, in) = tuple
      Try(JsonUtil.jsonToDescriptor(key)) match {
        case Failure(exception) => log.error("...")
        case Success(value)     => (key, in)
      }
    }
}
```

where `JsonUtil.jsonToDescriptor` is parsing the String as JSON. However, when I am applying

```
val myExtractTableInfo = ExtractTableInfo(true)

inputDStream.foreachRDD { rdd =>
  ...  
  rdd.mapPartitions(myExtractTableInfo)
  ...
}
```

then the compiler complains with:

```
Error:(71, 22) type mismatch;
```

Only when I extend the case class ExtractTableInfo with

```
extends (Iterator[(String, String)] => Iterator[(String, String))])
```

the code compiles and is running fine.

Can anyone explain what is happening here and why it is required to extend the case class with the same signature that is already given in the apply method?

Comment: did u follow all that?

Comment: Yes, I find the answer given below quite clear.

Comment: smarter than me it appears, I try to do spark with scala via the just enough approach

Comment: can you paste the actual correct statement in a comment pls, learnsome, get the FunctionX thing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at [Spark API](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.html#mapPartitions-scala.Function1-boolean-scala.reflect.ClassTag-), `mapPartitions` expects [Function1](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Function1.html) as argument. Class `ExtractTableInfo` simply don't have that trait without

```
extends (Iterator[(String, String)] => Iterator[(String, String))])
```

which is syntactic sugar for

```
extends Function1[Iterator[(String, String)], Iterator[(String, String)]]
```

Apply method simply overrides `()` operator but it does not make it a function. Lambdas could be used to convert it to a function i.e. both of these would work without implementing the trait:

```
rdd.mapPartitions(myExtractTableInfo(_))
rdd.mapPartitions(it => myExtractTableInfo(it))
```

To put it another way, we can take a look of value assignments:

```
// won't compile without implementing function trait
val f: Iterator[(String, String)] => Iterator[(String, String)] = myExtractTableInfo
// compiles happily
val f: Iterator[(String, String)] => Iterator[(String, String)] = it => myExtractTableInfo(it)
val f: Iterator[(String, String)] => Iterator[(String, String)] = myExtractTableInfo(_)
// apply is just syntactic sugar for ()
val f: Iterator[(String, String)] => Iterator[(String, String)] = myExtractTableInfo.apply(_)
```

Comment: I tried a similar example         rdd.mapPartitions(it => myExtractTableInfo(it)) and iyt all worked fine